# Duplicate commits after hg rebase

Tags: mercurial, dvcs

I know that rebasing, already public repo, is not a good idea since we can end up with duplicated changesets (they have different ids, but the changes are the same as for the source files).
Here's the snippet from [Mercurial Rebase Extension documentation](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/RebaseExtension):

> You should not rebase changesets that have already been shared with
>       others. Doing so will force everybody else to perform the same rebase or
>       they will end up with duplicated changesets after pulling in your rebased
>       changesets.

But I'm interested what exactly could be a problem with duplicated commits? Can you give me some example of the possible problems that might occur? I've tried merging two branches with duplicated commits and had no problems, just two changeset with the same name exist on the merged branch.

Answer (score 0):

> what exactly could be a problem with duplicated commits?

Dirty history, additional head -> the need for +1 merge